# Time complexity for recursion in for loop

Tags: time-complexity

```
func(n){
 if(n == 0){
   //print sth
   return;
 } 
 for(i=1;i<=6;i++){
   func(n-1)
 }
}
```

Please help me understand time complexity of above pseudo code.

Answer (score 10):

Your recursive code has the following properties:

- When you call the function with the argument 0, it does a constant amount of work and then returns.
- When you call the function with an argument n > 0, it does a constant amount of work and makes six recursive calls on problems of size n - 1.

Mathematically, we can model the total work done as a *recurrence relation*, letting T(n) denote the amount of work done when you call `func(n)`:

- T(0) = 1
- T(n) = 6T(n - 1) + 1

Let's play around with this and see what we find.

- T(0) = 1.
- T(1) = 6T(0) + 1 = 6 + 1 = 7.
- T(2) = 6T(1) + 1 = 6(7) + 1 = 43.
- T(3) = 6T(2) + 1 = 6(43) + 1 = 259.
- T(4) = 6T(3) + 1 = 6(259) + 1 = 1555.

It might not be obvious just by looking at this, the numbers here are actually given by the formula

> T(n) = (6<sup>n+1</sup> - 1) / 5

We can check this briefly as follows:

- T(0) = (6<sup>1</sup> - 1) / 5 = 5 / 5 = 1.
- T(1) = (6<sup>2</sup> - 1) / 5 = 35 / 5 = 7.
- T(2) = (6<sup>3</sup> - 1) / 5 = 215 / 5 = 43.

Asymptotically, this means that T(n) = Θ(6<sup>n</sup>), so the overall runtime is Θ(6<sup>n</sup>).

So... where did (6<sup>n+1</sup> - 1) / 5 come from? Notice that

- T(0) = 1
- T(1) = 6 · 1 + 1
- T(2) = 6<sup>2</sup> · 1 + 6 · 1 + 1
- T(3) = 6<sup>3</sup> · 1 + 6<sup>2</sup> · 1 + 6 · 1 + 1

More generally, T(n) seems to have the form

> 6<sup>n</sup> + 6<sup>n-1</sup> + ... + 6<sup>1</sup> + 6<sup>0</sup>.

This is the sum of a geometric series, which simplifies to (6<sup>n+1</sup> - 1) / 5.